# Committing multiple folders on separate drives with Git

Tags: git, version-control

I have a project spread across three separate folders (on two different drives), and I want to be able to make a single commit with files from all three folders.

Can Git do this? If not, what is my best option?

I am using Windows, and no, I can't simply move the folders unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being able to move the three different directories into one parent directory would be the ideal route, but if you can't do that, I would recommend making each of your three directories a repository of its own, and then create a "master repository" that has the three of them as submodules. The semantics for making updates and keeping things coordinated might be a little challenging, though...

Answer (score 0):

you can pass more then one argument

```
git add dir1 dir2
```

man pages can help you a lot: 
[git-add](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html)

Comment: When I try to add a file/folder outside of the repository, it gives me an error.